# 'Unconverted data remains' error when converting T0000 object to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My dataset looks a bit like so:

```
    RecordDate  Serial  RecordHour  Value
1   2015-03-18  304     T0000        0.0
2   2015-03-18  304     T0030        0.0
3   2015-03-18  304     T0100        0.0
```

My aim is to combine RecordDate and RecordHour in one column. I have converted RecordDate into datetime to enable this merge, but I am running into problems converting RecordHour (currently an Object).

I've tried several alternatives including:

```
df['RecordHour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['RecordHour'], format='T%H%M')
```

and

```
df['RecordHour'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, 'T%H%M'))
```

However all return the same error:

`ValueError: unconverted data remains: 0`

I've checked my dataset for any unexpected zeros in the RecordHour column, is it possible that 'T%H%M' isn't the right format for T0000 (etc.)?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert both at once *before* you convert `RecordDate` using:

```
df['Record_DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['RecordDate']+df['RecordHour'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H%M')

>>> df
   RecordDate  Serial RecordHour  Value     Record_DateTime
1  2015-03-18     304      T0000    0.0 2015-03-18 00:00:00
2  2015-03-18     304      T0030    0.0 2015-03-18 00:30:00
3  2015-03-18     304      T0100    0.0 2015-03-18 01:00:00
```

If there are problems with certain rows, you can use:

```
df['Record_DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['RecordDate']+df['RecordHour'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H%M',errors='coerce')
```

In which case it will return `NaT` where there are problematic entries

**Edit**: I'm thinking it might be that some of your entries simply have too many characters to be interpreted wit `T%H%M`. In this case, you can try cutting them off:

```
df['RecordHour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['RecordHour'].str[:5], format='T%H%M')
```